# GPU Utilization is low (not stable) in tensorflow distributed training in Datacrunch

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, tfrecord

I'm training my TensorFlow model in datacrunch with distributed MirroredStrategy (2 A100). I'm training on tfrecords datasets, where each tfrecords contains 600 audio files of length 10s. The sample rate for each audio is 48000. The problem is that while training, the GPU is not utilized correctly, and GPU utilization is not stable. I have monitored the GPU usage using nvidia-smi. The graph of GPU utilization over 160s while training is given below:
[image]

The code for preparing dataset is given below:

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_ds, compression_type='ZLIB', num_parallel_reads=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Prepare batches
ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

# Parse a batch into a dataset of [noisy, clean] pairs
ds = ds.map(lambda x: _parse_batch(x, sample_rate, duration, split)

if args.steps_per_epoch != -1 : ds = ds.repeat()

return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

And the parse batch method is:

```
def _parse_batch(record_batch, sample_rate, duration, split):
    n_samples = sample_rate * duration

    # Create a description of the features
    feature_description = {
        'noisy': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([n_samples], tf.float32),
        'clean': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([n_samples], tf.float32),
    }
    # Parse the input `tf.Example` proto using the dictionary above
    example = tf.io.parse_example(record_batch, feature_description)
    noisy, clean = tf.expand_dims(example['noisy'], axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(example['clean'], axis=-1)
    noisy, clean = augment(noisy, clean)
    return noisy, clean
```

Here is the code for augmentation:

```
def augment(noisy, clean):
    self_proba = 0.5
    self_initial = 0.3
    self_rt60 = (0.3, 1.3)
    self_first_delay = (0.01, 0.03)
    self_repeat = 3
    self_jitter = 0.1
    self_keep_clean = 0.1
    self_sample_rate = 48000

    if random.random() >= self_proba:
        return noisy, clean
    noise = noisy - clean
    initial = random.random() * self_initial
    first_delay = random.uniform(*self_first_delay)
    rt60 = random.uniform(*self_rt60)
    reverb_noise = _reverb(noise, initial, first_delay, rt60, self_repeat, self_jitter, self_sample_rate)
    noise += reverb_noise
    reverb_clean = _reverb(clean, initial, first_delay, rt60, self_repeat, self_jitter, self_sample_rate)
    clean += self_keep_clean * reverb_clean
    noise += (1 - self_keep_clean) * reverb_clean
    noisy = noise + clean
    return noisy, clean
```

Can anyone point out the reason behind not utilizing the GPU properly? How can I increase GPU utilization?

Comment: HI, you can try to use a debugger and observe when and where the GPU gets utilized - Do you use GPU at all in these data processing steps (the code shared) before the model starts to train? How is you GPU memory utilized? (is it like 15.9 GB out of 16 let's say?)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm kind of new. Can you tell me how can I debug the GPU utilization? Any resources will be helpful. I don't know that data processing are done in GPU or not. I didn't specified anything, they are default. I tried by running these data process steps before `with strategy.scope():` and within it, but both of them are same. MY GPU memory is utilized almost full all the time (80608MiB / 81251MiB).

Comment: you can debug with any IDE by setting breakpoints in the functions you wrote, run step by step and observe the utilization. Maybe try using nvidia-smi command as well. 
Regarding the percentage of utilization - some calculations may be not optimized for gpu. Try to see which precision you are using for your floats - try to reduce calculation steps where you can. If you can you can try to run the training on an instance with many CPU cores (> 32) for cross check the training speed.

Comment: I'm training my model in the cloud. There is no GUI environment, so I can't use an IDE. But I have tried nvidia-smi to monitor the GPU utilization. I have taken samples over some times and plotted them. I have updated the graph at the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: yes, exactly - I assume there are calculations that utilize the GPU up to high percentage and then some operation don't. Eventually, you can try some other GPU configurations and types if you are training in the cloud  - maybe that could help. I mean if you can't debug you can't really develop, therefore try different instances if you can.

Comment: What model are you using? Please add that information

Comment: Actually I have trained the same model on locally using a GTX1070, and GPU utilization was ok there. Almost all the time it was close to 100%. I'm only facing this issue on cloud where I'm using A100 GPU.

Comment: My model contains few custom ConV1D, Conv1Dtranspose, and Lstm layers.